# Permission denied when I try to change a file’s access and modification times

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina

I can't change a file’s access and modification times. When I enter `touch t- CCYYMMDDhhmm.SS file.example` , I get "permission denied". It works for other files. I tried to use `chmod +x file.example` but I am not sure I am using it correctly.  What should I write, please ?

Answer (score 2):

The command should be `touch -t (date) file.example`

`chmod +x` just makes the file executable – it should not affect the date - but if you still want to use it, you can do it like this:

```
chmod +x file.example
touch -t 0401200 file.example
```

Also, check that you have write permissions on the file by running `ls -l file.example` (or right-click on the file in Finder and choose Get Info, then look at 'Sharing & Permissions').